# How to use Alphasense NDIR CO2 sensor and OPC N2 particle sensor with Arduino/Rpi?

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, hardware

Does anyone have any experience with Alphasense NDIR CO2 sensor and OPC N2 particle sensor with with Arduino or Rpi?

I tried to get data out using both Arduino and Rpi separately, but maybe i the wiring was wrong or the coding was wrong, so none of them works now.

I would really appreciate any help on this subject please!

Comment: Pleas post your effort

Comment: For CO2 it only work with the software it came with but i am trying to make a small unit so even a laptop is too big that is why i am using Arduino/Rpi. Like i said i cant get data out using Arduino. I dont know how to attach a pdf in the post otherwise i will upload the instruction of the sensor.

Comment: For OPC N2 i found a library called py-opc but i dont know how to use it. Whenever i run the example code it came with "alpha" is not defined error comes out( https://github.com/dhhagan/py-opc )

Answer (score 0):

[`opc.FirmwareError`](http://py-opc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#opc.FirmwareError) is raised when the device cannot connect and execute the `opc.OpcN2.read_info_string()` method. This is necessary because Alphasense has changed the device quite significantly between the first few firmware versions, as it is a new device.

The `py-opc` library supports firmware versions 14-17, with version 18 supported on the `firmv18` branch which will be merged with master in the next few days.

If the device is still not working, it is probably a communications/wiring error. Make sure you have a good connection and are using the same 30 AWG wire their SPI-USB connector comes with. If all else fails, you can set up a Logic Analyzer to see exactly what's going on.